# Can I use/convert absolute normal maps in Blender?

Tags: normal-map, conversion

I have a model I got from... a place (I'm not able to show the actual model). It came with normal maps, but it's an *absolute* normal map rather than the more typical relative normal map. IOW, rather than encoding a *displacement* that is added to the model's geometric normal, it encodes the exact normal. (The model isn't intended to be animated, so it can get away with this render optimization.)

Now, I could probably code something up using GLSL to render the model in texture space and output the difference between the geometric normal and the normal map value... but that's a pain.

**Is there any way to turn an absolute normal map into a relative normal map *using only Blender*?** (Obviously I'll need both the geometry and the normal map.)

---

For anyone that doesn't understand the problem from the description, here's a mock-up of relative and absolute normal maps of a perfectly smooth (i.e. the normal map is a no-op) tube:

[image]

(Note that this is just a mock-up using a nine stop gradient; the interpolated values won't be quite right, and may not produce unit-length normals. However, it should be "close enough" to understand the difference between normal map types.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Blender allows you to choose what "space" a tangent map is in. The default, Tangent Space, corresponds to "relative" as in the question. There is also an Object Space option.

However, Blender's notion of the object space coordinate system may or may not be a match for the source normal map. While this can be fixed entirely within Blender using shader nodes, it's probably easier (and lossless) to convert the input normal map externally. For example, here is a Python script that swaps the red and green channels and inverts blue:

```py
import numpy
from PIL import Image

in_name = 'in.png'  # replace as needed or get from command line
out_name = 'out.png'  # likewise

# Read original normal map
data = numpy.array(Image.open(in_name))

# Swap R and G
data[:, :, [1, 0]] = data[:, :, [0, 1]]

# Invert B
data[:, :, 2] = 255 - data[:, :, 2]

# Write result
Image.fromarray(data).save(out_name)
```

You may need to experiment to determine what transformations (if any) are needed for your specific case. One way to do this is to bake normals with no normal map applied and inspect the resulting color values for known points on your model. You could compare single-channel images for both your "real" normal map and Blender's baked normal map. Extract each channel of each map as a grayscale image, and save both the original *and its inverse*. (Be careful to use linear color space throughout.) Then, figure out which pairs go together.

Note that a good way to tell if your normal map is "correct" is to change the strength between 0 and 1 repeatedly while using material preview shading. If everything is correct, you should see minimal change in your model. If the color/light changes significantly, you have swapped and/or inverted channels.